# Subtitles not showing up in browser's online player in pop os

Tags: chrome, pop-os, video-subtitles

I recently installed pop os. I'm trying to watch anime in google chrome but the subtitles doesn't show up. It worked fine in windows. I've tried different sites and different browsers but the subtitles from online players doesn't show up.